# Copy list with conditional mapping

Tags: mapstruct

I have a list of 
 1.Address object with ID,Street name,City and PostalCode
and a list of 
 2.Contact object with ID, Street,City and Phone.

Can i copy Street name and City alone
from List of Contact to List of Address based on ID matching ?

Address Object already has ID and Postalcode populated.
Contact Object already has ID and Street and City populated.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. MapStruct does not do conditional mapping. This is typically a business problem for which it is hard to predict what the user actually wants. You'll have to write a (default) method implementation or create a used mapper. On the bright side: if MapStruct recognizes the method signature at other call sites, it will select the handwritten method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881461/mapstruct-clear-collection-on-update-when-using-adders/54893824?noredirect=1#comment96571463_54893824) for more info.