# MapStruct: How to skip a particular property from copying where the property is inside a collection and the collection is inside the main entity

Tags: java, collections, dto, mapstruct

I am updating an existing bean using mapstruct. Below are my beans. As you can see my Entity bean has a collection of AnotherEntity bean.

```
public class Entity
{
private Integer id;
private String name;
private List<AnotherEntity> anotherEntityList = new ArrayList<AnotherEntity>();
//getters & setters
}

public class AnotherEntity
{
private Integer id;
private String text;
//getters & setters
}
```

Below is how i defined the mapping.

```
Entity updateEntityWithEntity(final Entity sourceEntity, @MappingTarget final Entity targetEntity);
```

Upon updating, i want mapstruct to skip the id property in the AnotherEntity bean.
Currently it is clearing the existing collection and creating a new collection with the values from source.

If i add the below

`@Mapping(target = "anotherEntityList", ignore = true)` it is ignoring the entire collection. But i want the collection but just ignore only the id property. Something like this. `@Mapping(target = "anotherEntityList.id", ignore = true)`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct cannot generate a list mapping. It would not know what the user actually would intent. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881461/mapstruct-clear-collection-on-update-when-using-adders/54893824#54893824) for more explanation.

But supposing that the lists are both ordered, and that element 0 needs to be mapped to target element 0, 1 to 1, etc.

You could do something like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper{

// you probably don't need the return, right?
void updateEntityWithEntity(Entity sourceEntity, @MappingTarget Entity targetEntity);

// you need to implement the list merging yourself.. MapStruct has no clue what you intent here
default updateList( List< AnotherEntity > sourceList, @MappingTarget List< AnotherEntity> targetList ) {
   for ( int i=0; i<sourceList.size(); i++ ) {
        updateAnotherEntityWithAnotherEntity( sourceList.get( i ), targetList.get( i ) );
   }
}

// used by above code in 
@Mapping( target = "id", ignore = true )
void updateAnotherEntityWithAnotherEntity(AnotherEntity sourceEntity, @MappingTarget AnotherEntity targetEntity);


}
```

Comment: Thanks. I too had the same thought but somehow it is not working. It is working for toEntity, toDTO methods but not for update. I mean for @MappingTarget. Generally it is deleting the entire collection and adding the collection coming from DTO. So it is not calling the new method you asked me to add.

Comment: Ah.. I remember. Mapstruct can't generate a list update method. Make the element mapping a non update and it will work. I'll update my example as soon as I've got access to my computer